# Multiple results when Run coming from more than one If Else Statement

Tags: java

I'm trying to get it to mix colors when the user enters two primary colors. The problem I have is the results come back with multiple results, some of which are incorrect. If the user enters the two colors Red and Yellow it will print the results that has even just one of those colors.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Please pick a primary color:");
        Scanner color = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = color.next();
        System.out.println("Please pick another primary color:");
        String input2 = color.next();
    
        {
            if(input.equals("Red")||input.equals("red")&&input2.equals("Blue")||
            input2.equals("blue"))
            {
                System.out.println("Red and Blue make Purple.");
            }
             else if(input.equals("Blue")||input.equals("blue")&&input2.equals("Red")||
            input2.equals("red"))
            {
                System.out.println("Blue and Red make Purple.");
            }
             else if(input.equals("Blue")||input.equals("blue")&&input2.equals("Yellow")||
            input2.equals("yellow"))
            {
                System.out.println("Blue and Yellow make Green.");
            }
             else if(input.equals("Yellow")||input.equals("yellow")&&input2.equals
            ("Blue")||input2.equals("blue"))
            {
                System.out.println("Yellow and Blue make Green.");
            }
             else if(input.equals("Yellow")||input.equals("yellow")&&input2.equals
             ("Red")||input2.equals("red"))
            {
                System.out.println("Yellow and Red make Orange.");
            }
            else if(input.equals("Red")||input.equals("red")&&input2.equals
            ("Yellow")||input2.equals("yellow"))
            {
                System.out.println("Red and Yellow make Orange.");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Enter a Valid Primary colors.");
            }
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your given conditions are wrong. It should be:

```
if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("red") && input2.equalsIgnoreCase("Blue"))
        {
            System.out.println("Red and Blue make Purple.");
        }
         else if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("blue") && input2.equalsIgnoreCase("Red")
        {
            System.out.println("Blue and Red make Purple.");
        }
         else if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("blue") && input2.equalsIgnoreCase("Yellow"))
        {
            System.out.println("Blue and Yellow make Green.");
        }
         else if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("yellow") && input2.equalsIgnoreCase("blue"))
        {
            System.out.println("Yellow and Blue make Green.");
        }
         else if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("yellow") && input2.equalsIgnoreCase("Red"))
        {
            System.out.println("Yellow and Red make Orange.");
        }
        else if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("red") && input2.equalsIgnoreCase("Yellow"))
        {
            System.out.println("Red and Yellow make Orange.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a Valid Primary colors.");
        }
```

So why your condition is wrong?

Well, you're checking whether `statement1 is true OR (statement1 & 2 is true) OR statement2 is true`. As a result, if any of these 3 segments joined by OR is true, the whole condition becomes true.

For example, in your first condition, you gave:

```
if(input.equals("Red") || input.equals("red") && input2.equals("Blue") || input2.equals("blue"))
```

So, if a user inputs Red and Black, this whole condition will satisfy, as the first part `input.equals("Red")` is true.
That is why you'll get `"Red and Blue make Purple."`

Hope you understand what's going on here.

Comment: This was extremely helpful. I am still learning so explaining it the way you did gave me that "ohhhhhhh yeah, that makes sense" moment.

Comment: To complete the answer: the `&&` operator has more priority than `||`.

Comment: @ChristyPomerleau, if this answers your question, please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the conditions of the if statements.
`(input.equals("Red")||input.equals("red")&&input2.equals("Blue")||input2.equals("blue"))`

should be:
`((input.equals("Red")||input.equals("red"))&&(input2.equals("Blue")||input2.equals("blue")))`

The reason for this change is due to how the computer calculates the value of the expressions. It calculates from right to left, meaning that `input2.equals("Blue")||input2.equals("blue")` is going to get evaluated first. So far, there is nothing wrong with this, let's move on to the next step.

`input.equals("red")&&(input2.equals("Blue")||input2.equals("blue"))` *(I added in the extra parentheses so that you can see what the computer sees if you don't specify the parentheses yourself.)* This expression is also good so far, if the first input is red and the other is (blue or Blue). The problem lies in the final step.

`(input.equals("Red")||(input.equals("red")&&(input2.equals("Blue")||input2.equals("blue")))`
This expression says that if the first input is Red **OR** (red and (blue or Blue) it should execute whatever there is to execute, so if the first input is Red, it will execute the if statement's body.

Even better would be the use of the `String.equalsIgnoreCase()` method:
`(input.equalsIgnoreCase("red")&&input2.equalsIgnoreCase("blue"))`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @GaëlJ, edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you. This was also very helpful.